# recover local_db.bin

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo, datanucleus

using App Engine and Java I decided to delete the local datastore located in local_db.bin as I had made some changes to class models contained in it. Mistake!
Such local_db file is not created anymore, running the app I get
"The backing store, G:\workspace\test\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created."

but it isn´t. The app runs smoothly time after time and the database is never created (I tried stopping the jetty server and even closing Eclipse).

Any idea? (otherwise I guess I´ll create a new project and migrate the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is created when data is persisted, but not necessary direct. I deleted my version as a test. Persisted some data. at which point the same message you got was shown. And after some time I got this message: `Time to persist datastore: 37 ms`. (When deleting the `local_db.bin` I also deleted the `datastore-indexes-auto.xml`).

Comment: Done, as you said local_db.bin is created only when some data is persisted (my init-db subroutine wasn´t working). Thanks!.